# How to dereference and print each element of a pointer array?

Tags: c++, gdb

Let's say I have an array of pointers:

```
struct S {int x;};
S *arr[3] = {new S{1}, new S{2}, new S{3}};
```

I want to make `gdb` dereference and print each element of the array.

Printing one element is simple:

```
(gdb) p *arr[0]                                                                                            
$1 = {x = 1}
```

but I want to print *every* element in the array in this fashion.

I tried `p arr`, but it outputs the pointers, rather than the objects they point to:

```
(gdb) p arr
$1 = {0x613c20, 0x613c40, 0x613c60}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found better than that:

```
(gdb) set $i=0
(gdb) p *arr[$i++]
$102 = {x = 1}
(gdb) 
$103 = {x = 2}
(gdb) 
$104 = {x = 3}
(gdb)
```

maybe it can help.

**note:** simply press `return` to show the next value.

Comment: can i use for in gdb?

Comment: thank you,i have sovled all problem,because i can use while in gdb,and it can comletely sovle the problem,although its little complex